# Stock broker's profit margin & criteria

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much do brokerages pay exchanges per trade?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/18280/how-much-do-brokerages-pay-exchanges-per-trade)
>   [What do brokerage firms do?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/18401/what-do-brokerage-firms-do)

How much does it cost a broker to trade a company's stock on your behalf? Is it different for different SEC (Nasdaq and NYSE)? What is the criteria for becoming a broker?

Comment: One answer to your first question can be found [here](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/18284/5760), and following the link there will likely reveal the answer to the second. The third question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE!  Take a look around, and please glance at our [FAQ].